# jQuery using tab to go through dropdown menu links (keyboard accessibility)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a css menu I would like to make accessible through keyboard interaction. I want to be able to tab through each link including sub menu links.

If the dropdown focus moves on to the next parent link dropdown then the previous dropdown should hide.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hectooorr/gsgskpgy)**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="custom-MainMenu-TopNav-li">
        <div>
            <span><a href="#">Parent link 1</a></span>
            <div>
                <ul class="custom-MainMenu-SubNav-dropdown">
                   <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="custom-MainMenu-TopNav-li">
        <div>
            <span>Parent link 2</span>
            <div>
                <ul class="custom-MainMenu-SubNav-dropdown">
                   <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
accessibleDropdown();
    function accessibleDropdown(){

        jQuery('.custom-MainMenu-TopNav-li a').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).focus(function(){
                jQuery(this).addClass('focused');
                var menuParent = jQuery(this).parent().next().find('ul');
                jQuery(menuParent).css('display','block');
            });

            jQuery(this).blur(function(){
                jQuery(this).removeClass('focused');
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: I m not clear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: a snippet or fiddle would help

Comment: @Claudiu

The focus is so I can use a keyboard to tab through each link. If I tab through a parent link. So for example, I would tab and reach 'Parent link 1' and at this point I would see the 'custom-mainmenu-subnav-dropdown' and be able to tab through those. Then once I reach the end I would go on to 'Parent link 2' and the 'Parent link 1' dropdown menu would hide. I would then continue going through each link under 'Parent link 2'. Hope that helps! 
     
Fiddle jsfiddle.net/hectooorr/gsgskpgy

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your desired outcome and need for this result, but hopefully this will help you out.

I had to redo your example due to naming convention and approach, but I assume this is what you wanted...

**Here's a demo, just in case...**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLden/Ltz7nmdb/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Parent Link</a>

        <ul class="navbar-sub">
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">One</a>
            </li>

            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Two</a>
            </li>

            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Parent Link</a>

        <ul class="navbar-sub">
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">One</a>
            </li>

            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Two</a>
            </li>

            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Parent Link</a>

        <ul class="navbar-sub">
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">One</a>
            </li>

            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Two</a>
            </li>

            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Parent Link</a>

        <ul class="navbar-sub">
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">One</a>
            </li>

            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Two</a>
            </li>

            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.navbar,
.navbar .navbar-sub {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar > .navbar-item {
    float: left;
}

.navbar > .navbar-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.navbar > .navbar-item.active > .navbar-sub {
    display: block;
}

.navbar > .navbar-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar > .navbar-item > a {
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #696969;
    display: block;
}

.navbar > .navbar-item > a:hover,
.navbar > .navbar-item > a:focus,
.navbar > .navbar-item.active > a {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.navbar .navbar-sub {
    display: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-sub > .navbar-sub-item > a {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #696969;
}

.navbar .navbar-item.active .navbar-sub-item > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-item.active .navbar-sub-item > a:focus {
    background-color: #999;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.navbar').on('mouseenter focusin', '.navbar-item > a', function () {
    $(this)
        .parent('.navbar-item')
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings('.navbar-item')
        .removeClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

here you go, simple jquery :)

```js
// display drop down box when mouse is over
$(".custom-MainMenu-TopNav-li a").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).find(".custom-MainMenu-SubNav-dropdown").css("display", "block");
});

// hide drop down box when mouse leaves
$(".custom-MainMenu-TopNav-li a").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find(".custom-MainMenu-SubNav-dropdown").css("display", "none");
});
```

This basically displays/hide each the dropdown when the mouse is over/leaves the parent div.

I don't think it would be a good idea to display the dropbown menu on focus, cause i believe you can only focus on certain elements like inputs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to have focus to maintain the menu accessible to users using only a keyboard